# wrong/stale username on gitbash on windows

Tags: windows, git, git-bash

I had a windows user (admin) `Foo`.
It was an online user coming after a fresh Windows installation which didn't allow me to use a local user only.

After installing Windows, I created a new user `Bar` and removed the previous user.

I installed now git for windows, but every time I open git-bash it seems to recognize as user the old one, despite it doesn't exist anymore (note that the old user folder is still there for some reasons).

Note that from git-bash I can't even edit files on the new (and only active user `Bar`). Permission are denied despite is the new only user in the system.

Any idea how to fix this?